# Installing latest version of Python on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS without building from source

Tags: 14.04, python3

I am looking for a reliable choice.

How to install Python 3.4.3 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS without building from source?

Comment: "How to install Python 3.4.3 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS without building from source?"...well that's the default version of python3 on 14.04, install via `sudo apt-get install python3`. For the latest version of python follow edwinksl's link.